# Create numeration column based on sequences from 0 to 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with sequences that start with 0 and go up to any number, then back to 0. I now want to create a new column which give those sequences indeces.
Those sequences should start with the first 0 before and end with the first 0 after the sequence.

```
index   value
 0        0
 1        0
 2        3   
 3        8
 4        4
 5        0
 6        0
 7        0
 8        2 
 9        8
 10       7
 11       9
 12       4
 13       0
```

Output should look like this

```
index   value   seq
 0        0     NaN
 1        0      1
 2        3      1
 3        8      1
 4        4      1
 5        0      1
 6        0     NaN
 7        0      2
 8        2      2
 9        8      2
 10       7      2
 11       9      2
 12       4      2
 13       0      2
```

I haven't found any solution yet and would appreciate help.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a temporary data frame called `tmp` representing your groups. The groups can be generated by comparing your original and shifted column named 'value' with 0. You can then just apply `cumsum` on that boolean mask to create your groups. In order to get rid off the zero values between two other zero values (necessary to get `nan` values in the end), you can count the occurrence of each group and only maintain those that occur more than once. This temporary data frame can then easily be joined with your initial data frame.

Note: Since your desired 'seq' column contains `nan` values, it must be a `float` type.

Code:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "value": [0, 0, 3, 8, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 7, 9, 4, 0]
})

tmp = (
    (df.eq(0) & df.eq(0).shift(1)).cumsum()
    .groupby("value", as_index=False)["value"].transform("count")
    .query("value > 1")
    .groupby("value").ngroup().add(1)
)

df.join(tmp.to_frame().rename(columns={0: "seq"}))
```

Output:

```py
    value   seq
0   0       NaN
1   0       1.0
2   3       1.0
3   8       1.0
4   4       1.0
5   0       1.0
6   0       NaN
7   0       2.0
8   2       2.0
9   8       2.0
10  7       2.0
11  9       2.0
12  4       2.0
13  0       2.0
```